# Errors in Windows Forms controls in designer view

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms

On occasion, I get the following error in design mode of some user controls in Visual Studio 2008:

> The file 'UserControl.vb' does not
>   support code parsing or generation
>   because it is not contained within a
>   project that supports code.

It doesn't happen on a consistent basis, but it happens enough to be annoying.  Are there any common causes of this error?

And yes, it is in a project that supports code - last I checked, WinForms projects typically have code in them!

Comment: That is strange indeed!  I've never experienced this issue, but off the top of my head I'd say to recompile the entire solution.  Probably won't help though, which is why I didn't post this as an answer.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is a bug in VS. It happens in VS2005 as well.

Don't waste your time: close VS, open it again and everything should work fine.

Comment: So freakin annoying. Fix the bugs instead of focusing on building a new version every other year.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I'm using 2010 and just got this error.

Comment: Neither does it work after uninstalling then re-installing VS2012. *C'est frustrant!*

Comment: Happens in VS2012 too on a brand new project after a virgin install of VS2012. Opening and closing does not fix it.

Comment: Same here on VS 2008.

Comment: Same on VS 2017. Good job Microsoft on those pesky bugs! :)

Comment: Same on VS 2019.

Answer (score 5):

Note that there is a Microsoft Connect issue on this: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=366006

Comment: This answer should be converted to a comment.

Comment: Posted 1 month after the accepted answer, it should be a comment for that answer, not another answer.

Comment: Link seems to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

I had reverted (through source control) changes to my project file, which removed the file from my solution (specifically the .Designer file). However, I still had the file open in Visual Studio and attempting to show the designer for it caused this error.

I clicked the "Show All Files" button at the top of Solution Explorer, found the files that weren't included. Right-clicking and selecting "Include in Project" and rebuilding fixed the issue for me.