# What does it mean when Visual Studio tells me my project doesn't support code?

Tags: visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Errors in Windows Forms controls in designer view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369393/errors-in-windows-forms-controls-in-designer-view)

The file 'C:\Users[path removed]\ReportForm.cs' does not support code parsing or generation because it is not contained within a project that supports code.

[image]

Comment: Can you give more information?

Answer (score 5):

I've come across this one when I've renamed a form then closed and re-opened VS.  The error is thrown and I can't see the designer.  The remedy for me was checking to make sure the project form is looking for my newly named form and not the old name, if it is the old name then just delete it and add->existing item.

All should be good from that point.

Comment: In my case I had just renamed the form and walked away. When I came back the next morning Windows Update had rebooted my PC.  I deleted the project.sou file and everything was okay.

Answer (score 2):

The solution that helped me was that I was running my VS in compatibility mode and also as an administrator.

In order to make it run smoothly you have to uncheck the "compatibility" and "Run as administrator" options.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that the problem is a lack of supporting code.  It's more likely that the code in ReportForm.cs or ReportForm.designer.cs is not parsable by the WinForms designer class.  You can verify this by deleting all of your code and type in something very simple and reload the designer.

Example:

```
public class ReportForm(){ 
  public ReportForm(){}
}
```

Comment: Missing empty constructor of the form