# Visual Studio Designer won't work for a C++/CLI file in VS2012 while it did in VS2005. Know why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli, visual-studio-designer

I know, I know, this issue has been addressed many times. "Just forward declare your class before any other forward declarations and it will work."

I re-open this question because for me it doesn't work at all. I have Visual Studio 2012 update 1. I develop in C++/CLI in x64 on Win 7/x64. Here is how my header file looks like:

```
#pragma once

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    ref class MyForwardDeclaredClass;

    public ref class MyClass : public System::Windows::Forms::UserControl
    {
    public:
        // My declaration here

        MyForwardDeclaredClass^ mObjectPtr;
    }
}
```

When I launch the design, I get the message **The class MyClass can be designed, but is not the first class in the file. Visual Studio requires that designers use the first class in the file.**

So, following the recommendations of many persons (and these recommendations seem to work for many), I added the line:

```
ref class MyClass; // <-- ADDED FORWARD DECLARATION HERE!
ref class MyForwardDeclaredClass;

public ref class MyClass : public System::Windows::Forms::UserControl
{
    // ...
```

and I still get the same error message. Notice that *I also restarted Visual Studio*, *I cleaned the project*, and *I rebuilt it*.

Note: I tried to remove the forward declaration and to add a #include "MyForwardDeclaredClass.h" instead. I got the same error.

We migrated from VS2005 to VS2012 recently. With VS2005, the designer use was so-so. But it worked most of the time. Now, most of the time I cannot make it work and I don't find any workaround.

Any idea?

**EDIT**

OK, following the advices I was given, I erased the .suo and the .sdf files then reloaded the solution then rebuilt it. Nothing good. I recreate a new project using the same code files: nothing good. And yes, *I have .cpp files in my project* ;-)

Comment: You might try deleting the .sdf and .suo files that Visual Studio generates next to the solution.

Comment: Hi Nathan! I did what you suggested and I got this error message: "The file 'MyClass.h' does not support code parsing or generation because it is not contained within a project that supports code. What???

Comment: Here they say just to close & reopen visual studio and it should clear up?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369393/errors-in-windows-forms-controls-in-designer-view

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way neither.

Comment: At this point I would try re-creating the project from scratch and adding the files back in.  I'm pretty much stumped as to what's going wrong for you :(

Comment: I made a new project, re-built it and **nothing** changed.

Comment: I know this seems like a dumb question but... Do you have .cpp files in the project? If it's just headers I imagine you'd have problems like this. Come to think of it you might want to post your .vcxproj file here and maybe someone can spot something.

Comment: I **do** have .cpp files in my project. Nice try... FYI, other programmers succeed to view the designer for the same file/project. Thus it seems to be related to my VS setup (or my computer setup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was quite easy: I had to reset default options in **Tools-Options-Text Editor-C/C++/Advanced**, section **Browsing/Navigation**.

If someday you experience the same problem, just try to restore the default values for these options.

Comment: I'm having the same problem: I have not changed these options, just converted a VS2010 .sln to 2012.  What are the default values?  I see no way to just reset to default..