# Visual Studio does not support code parsing or generation because it is not contained within a project that supports code

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, eventhandler

I am building a Windows Form Application, I have a `Form1.cs` file and `Form1.Designer.cs` file. After I added a private method inside a `Form1` class in `Form1.cs` it was working, but after I closed VS code and opened it again it was saying

> "does not support code parsing or generation because it is not contained within a project that supports code". [Call Stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lQB5.jpg)

I have deleted the private method I've added in Form1 class and re-opened Project again, but it says the same thing

```
namespace Project
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MyFunc()
        {
            //some code here
        }
        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          MyFunc();
        }
    }
}
```

I expected `Button1_Click` event handler to call my own method

Comment: Is is VS or VS code ?Did you tried restarting your Visual Studio ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Errors in Windows Forms controls in designer view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369393/errors-in-windows-forms-controls-in-designer-view)

Comment: Wamiq Rehman, Yes I restarted VS code a lot of times